# Eclipse android projects generating Problems

Tags: java, android, eclipse, r.java-file

my eclipse started acting weird,

1. when i create new projects it doesnt generate any files nor packages, no R.java, nothing. it just creates the folders. It worked perfectly before.
2. In the projects that exist i have to manually add Ids to the R.java file because it stopped updating on its own
3. Wierd problems with variables, highlated red when everything is ok and then after restarting eclipse everything is fine, That might connect with the R.java problem though.
4. It started to crash when i try to open projects from my first workspace and had to create a new ones. I need to do an app quickly and cant start because of this. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall Eclipse. It will be faster than trying to figure out why it is not behaving correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating eclipse, then updating with the SDK manager. But I second Ak_Crusader, just reinstall the lastest version.